# Wordpress problem redirecting in the logging form

Tags: php, wordpress

I used a plugin for a form login in a new page. When user logged (or not) redirect to a website. But when I create the page show this error:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-includes/class.wp-styles.php:287) in
>   /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1281
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-includes/class.wp-styles.php:287) in
>   /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1284

Code:

```
//Redirecting logged users to home page
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    wp_redirect( get_option('home') );// redirect to home page
    exit;
}

// if there's a valid referrer, and it's not the default log-in screen
    if ( !empty($referrer) && !strstr($referrer,'wp-login') && !strstr($referrer,'wp-admin') ){
        wp_redirect( $referrer . '/?login=failed' );
        exit;
    }
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put it inside a `init` hook this should fix your problem.

Here's an example how you should do this.

```php
add_action('init', function() {
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        wp_redirect( get_option('home') );
        exit;
    }

    if ( !empty($referrer) && !strstr($referrer,'wp-login') && !strstr($referrer,'wp-admin') ){
        wp_redirect( $referrer . '/?login=failed' );
        exit;
    }
});
```

Above code has not been tested! It is only an example.

The reason why we put it inside the `init` hook is because `init` is fired and executed before the headers are sent.